# Как сделать итерацию по данным в hex формате

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно проитерировать хэши sha256 по строке hex + дополнительное число
используется только hex

Может так будет понятнее:
есть слово в hex, мне нужно к нему добавить еще одно слово в hex
это второе слово должно принимать значения от 0 до 0xFFFFFFFF

```
from hashlib import sha256

number = 'badc975d17'
add_number = 'a23d693b' #это доп.число мне нужно проитерировать с 0 до 2^32
all_number = number + add_number
all_number_hex = binascii.a2b_hex(all_number)

hash = sha256(sha256(all_number_hex).digest()).digest()
check = binascii.b2a_hex(hash[::-1])

print(check)
print(num2[-8:])
```

проблема в том, если я беру for in add_number, как строку не пропускает
а также еще binascii.b2a_hex ругается когда нечетное количество символов, символов всегда должно быть 8, формат "FFFFFFFF"
помогите чем кто сможет, я уже всю голову сломал и запутался в конец.

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
import binascii
number = 'badc975d17'
i = 0
for i in range(0xffffffff):                       #range(2**32-1)
    add_number = '{:08x}'.format(i)               #type <str> 00000000
    all_number = number + add_number              #concat <str>
    byte_all_number = bytes.fromhex(all_number)   #convert to bytes
    byte_digest = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(byte_all_number).digest()).digest()
    hash = binascii.b2a_hex(byte_digest[::-1])    #convert to hex
    print(hash)
```